# Go XML Marshal: Unintended Output of Slice

Tags: xml, go, slice, marshalling

There is a structure with a slice being one of its members:

```golang
type Package struct {
    Name string
    ...
    Files []File
}

type File struct {
    Name string
    ...
}
```

I used `encoding/xml` to marshal this structure. This is what I got:

```xml
<Package>
    <Name>example</Name>
    <Files>
        <Name>Example1</Name>
    </Files>
    <Files>
        <Name>Example2</Name>
    </Files>
</Package>
```

which is not the behavior I intended. I wanted to marshal it into this format:

```xml
<Package>
    <Name>example</Name>
    <Files>
        <File>
            <Name>Example1</Name>
        </File>
        <File>
            <Name>Example2</Name>
        </File>
    </Files>
</Package>
```

I am new to Golang and haven't known much about its slice and marshalling mechanism. Although it sounds like a stupid question, how can I achieve the intended (second) format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The marshaling and unmarshaling rules are well laid out in the relevant documentation of [`encoding/xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/). For example the section on [`xml.Marshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal) says:

> If a field uses a tag "a>b>c", then the element c will be nested
> inside parent elements a and b. Fields that appear next to each other
> that name the same parent will be enclosed in one XML element.

---

So you should be able to achieve what you want with this:

```golang
type Package struct {
    Name  string
    Files []File `xml:"Files>File"`
}

// this also works
type Package struct {
    Name  string
    Files []File `xml:">File"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/gg-6Tj3WNnV

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explaination!